# Need Cron Expression to run scheduler every 3 hours starting at 3 am

Tags: java, cron, quartz-scheduler

I need cron expression for quartz scheduler to run scheduler every 3 hours starting at 3 am. I tried below, however it is skipping 12 am run everyday.
0 0 3/3 * * ?

I am unable to understand what exactly needs to be modified in above to get that 12 am run as well.
Kindly help.

Comment: Try "0 0 3/3 ? * * *"

Answer (score 0):

try 0 0 3,6,9,12 * * ? .
can read the official doc , get more information about the  expression .

Answer (score 0):

It should be

> 0 0 3/3 ? * * *

You can use online cron makers to validate / construct crons. Here is a handy tool https://www.freeformatter.com/cron-expression-generator-quartz.html

Comment: This does not include 12 am run:(

Answer (score 0):

You can try:

```
1 3/3 * * *
```

This translates to "At minute 1 past every 3rd hour from 3 through 23". Crontab.guru is an excellent resource.